# How do I filter sub document (array) based on some predicate in Meteor publication?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-publications

I am trying to filter not just the fields but objects inside my array field. Referring to the example below, for segments field, I want my client to only get those objects in the **segments** array where `isReleased === true`

Example Schema

```
{
    _id:      123456,
    segments: [
        {
            name: 'Type A',
            isReleased: false,
        },
        {
            name: 'Type B',
            isReleased: false,
        },
        {
            name: 'Type C',
            isReleased: true,
        }
    ],
}
```

So basically, I want my client to just receive,

```
{
    _id:      123456,
    segments: [
        {
            name: 'Type C',
            isReleased: true,
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents) operator. The query would be like this:

```
Schema.find({segments: {$elemMatch: {isReleased: true}}},...)
```

You can check the examples on the link for more details.